# Problema al convertir string a clase List<T> C# Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, wcf

Tengo una aplicacion a la que le agregue una referecia WCF y la configure para consumir un servicio Web hasta alli perfecto ,el problema es que obtengo el response del web service y lo nesecito convertir en una List escribi el siguiente metodo no me devuelve error pero las List todos sus valores quedan null aunque tiene 300 posiciones.

es decir algo asi para todas las posiciones:

```
**Nombre:null
Apellido:null
Edad:0
FechaNacimiento:01/01/1900**
```

Que puedo hacer para solucionar esto ??

```
 public async Task<List<KactusEmpleado>> UseKactusAsync()
        {
            string userWcf = EngineStf.UserWcf;
            string passwordWcf = EngineStf.PasswordWcf;
            DateTime Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-04-26");
            KactusIntegration.KWsGhst2Client wsGhst2Client = new KactusIntegration.KWsGhst2Client();
            var response = await wsGhst2Client.ConsultarEmpleadosAsync(499, Fecha , userWcf, passwordWcf);
            string resultado = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
            List<KactusEmpleado> KactusEmpleado = new List<KactusEmpleado>();
            KactusEmpleado = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KactusEmpleado>>(resultado);
            return KactusEmpleado;
        }
```

En las imagenes se ve que obtego datos pero al pasarlos a la lista los valores no son seteados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tienes en `resultado`?

Comment: En resultado una cadena de tipo JSON  con todos los valores que obtengo

Comment: Es extraño. Entiendo que el problema lo tienes aqui entonces `KactusEmpleado = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KactusEmpleado>>(resultado);`. Has comprobado que coincida exactamente la estructura de ese json con `KactusEmpleado`?, porque tu código a mi me parece correcto. Si es asi, tal vez un [mcve] nos ayudaría (por ejemplo, un ejemplo de ese json y la definicion de `KactusEmpleado`

Answer (score 2):

Parece que tu variable `response` ya devuelve un array `KacktusEmpleado[]`, por tanto no utilices la serialización para convertirlo, puedes añadir:

```
using System.Linq;
```

en la cabecera del fichero y luego usar lo siguiente:

```
List<KacktusEmpleado> kacktusEmpleados = response.ToList();
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque serializas y vuelves a deserializar. Si te llega un json del servicio web solo tiene que deserializar siempre y cuando recibas un servicio Rest.

```
public async Task<List<KactusEmpleado>> UseKactusAsync()
            {
                string userWcf = EngineStf.UserWcf;
                string passwordWcf = EngineStf.PasswordWcf;
                DateTime Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-04-26");
                KactusIntegration.KWsGhst2Client wsGhst2Client = new KactusIntegration.KWsGhst2Client();
                var response = await wsGhst2Client.ConsultarEmpleadosAsync(499, Fecha , userWcf, passwordWcf);

            List<KactusEmpleado> KactusEmpleado = new List<KactusEmpleado>();
            KactusEmpleado = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KactusEmpleado>>(response);
            return KactusEmpleado;
        }
```

Por lo que veo hay una posibilidad de que tu servicio sea SOAP y la manera de llamarlo sea traves de Referencia Web desde boton derecho sobre el proyecto, el menu agregar -> Referencia de Servicio. Si es asi solo debes:

```
public async Task<List<KactusEmpleado>> UseKactusAsync()
            {
List<KactusEmpleado> KactusEmpleados = new List<KactusEmpleado>();
                string userWcf = EngineStf.UserWcf;
                string passwordWcf = EngineStf.PasswordWcf;
                DateTime Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-04-26");
                KactusIntegration.KWsGhst2Client wsGhst2Client = new KactusIntegration.KWsGhst2Client();
               KactusEmpleados = await wsGhst2Client.ConsultarEmpleadosAsync(499, Fecha , userWcf, passwordWcf);

            return KactusEmpleados;
        }
```